# Terminal Git vs Terminal Node vs Terminal Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, git, terminal

Estou com alguma dificuldade em perceber a necessidade de ter tantos terminais instalados no computador quando preciso usar o git ou node.js. Quais são as diferenças entre os terminais, o que um pode fazer e o outro não? 
Por exemplo:
eu quis verificar se tinha o Node.js instalado no meu Windows 10, para isso fiz `which node` no terminal Windows e sem sucesso, eu percebo que esse comando não está implementado nesse terminal e tenho de usar outro (o Git deu-me o caminho da instalação), mas como saber qual deles usar para cada tarefa se no artigo/tutorial não está especificado?

Comment: Se você tiver feito a instalação como global qualquer um dos terminais vai fazer o que você quiser. O problema é que o terminal do windows não reconhece o comando "which", mas pra todas as operações essenciais funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma bem simples, os "terminais" (como são chamados) ou **CLI**s (**C**ommand **L**ine **I**nterface) são software que te permitem executar comandos, tais comandos podem ser outros software compilado ou simples scripts escritos especificamente para o CLI "x" e interpretado também por ele.

**Por que tantos?**

Não há uma real necessidade de ter todos, a principal diferença de cada um é como ele é configurado e escrito, o que acaba implicando nos comandos que ele conseguirá rodar.

O terminal do Node, por exemplo, já vem com o comando `node` disponível, diferente do GitBash, que vem com os comandos de `git` disponíveis, enquanto o terminal padrão do Windows não tem nenhum deles.

**De onde vêm esses comandos?**

Cada terminal irá procurar por comandos compatíveis nos lugares onde ele está configurado para procurar. O CMD do Windows, por exemplo, irá consumir a variável de ambiente `PATH`, indexando todos os comandos compatíveis ao abrir o terminal e toda vez que você der um comando, o CMD irá tentar utilizar algum desses comandos e caso ele tenha achado, irá executá-lo.

Esses "comandos" podem ser arquivos `.exe` e, no CMD `.bat`. O Terminal no Mac consegue rodar arquivos `.bash`, mas não os `.bat` e por aí vai.

**Qual o melhor?**

Vai do gosto e da necessidade, eu uso bastante (em ambiente Windows) o emulador [cmder](http://cmder.net/), o CLI [GitBash](http://gitforwindows.org/) e o CLI CMD.

**Você ainda pode adicionar o programa que quiser** (desde que seja compatível) em qualquer CLI, para adicionar o `node` no CMD, por exemplo, você só precisa incluir o caminho do arquivo `node.exe` na `PATH` do Windows. E isto significa que você pode escolher e utilizar a CLI que quiser.